# Regex match content of last parenthesis set

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, I have this regex for matching content (group 1) inside parenthesis: `\((.*?)\)`

It is working great, but I would like it to only match the last occurrence of a set of parenthesis:

Test: "(no(yes)"
With my regex the group 1 is `no(yes)` but I would like it to return `yes`.

Thank you!

Precision: This is regarding the last **set** of parenthesis which means that "(no(yes + (1 - 3))" should return `yes + (1 - 3)`
So `\(([^()]+)\)` is not working as the content of the last set of parenthesis could contain parenthesis.

Comment: Use `.*\((.*?)\)`, get Group 1 value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not working

Comment: What is your regex tool/flavor?

Comment: @anubhava javascript

Comment: But `(no(yes + (1 - 3))` is not well balanced

Comment: @anubhava that is the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your provided examples, you may try this regex:

```sh
\(((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*)\)[^(]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgZkSu/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\(`: Match a `(`
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `\([^()]*\)`: Match a `(...)` substring
    - `|`: OR
    - `[^()]`: Match a character that is not `(` and `)`
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `)`: End capture group
- `\)`: Match closing `)`
- `[^(]*`: Make sure there is not a `(` before end
- `$`: End

Comment: this only works with two levels of nesting.

Comment: still no luck with `(A ((B)) C)`

Comment: @Gruvw: `(A ((B)) C)` has all balanced parentheses but your examples showed unbalanced parentheses and I conformed that in comments as well. As per requirements given this matches `(B)` since that is last pair of `(...)`. If you update your questions with more details I will try to tweak however do keep in mind that Javascript regex does not support recursive pattern matching like PCRE.

Comment: Nice! @anubhava -I've created [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/odX4ss/1), `(?<=[^(]*\()[^)]*\)(?=\)|$)` which finds the correct match in two of the three strings. At the moment, I am not able to think beyond it, this is where your expertise will be needed.